# I am parsing JIRA ticket using groovy and it is taking some extra characters. Any idea how can this be skipped?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jira, jenkins-groovy, jira-rest-api

I am trying to parse a JIRA ticket using the JIRA API in a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy code. However, my code is creating a list with extra characters, resulting in the following output:

```
{{color:#172b4d}abc-service=1000.1.438{color}, {color:#172b4d}abcsvcVersion=2.2.3-Rel.2088{color}}
```

But I expect the output to be:

```
{abc-service=1000.1.438, abcsvcVersion=2.2.3-Rel.2088}
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this issue?

---

Comment: What code do you have?